# Find android usb mode status programmatically

Tags: android, usb, mtp, usb-mass-storage

Is there a way to detect which usb mode is enabled?

Before, using `Settings.Global.USB_MASS_STORAGE_ENABLED`
was easy.

But now, with MTP / PTP / charging only, how can we detect which mode is enabled? Both in case a device is already connected (so by looping over `usbManager.getDeviceList();`) or by checking some system setting?

I am talking only about detecting and not changing it, without being rooted.

Comment: I have also same problem. Did you solve this?

Comment: no, I did  not :)